# MongoDB Stitch - How to keep datatype to int when decremented with update?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb-stitch

I am using mongodb stitch function, I have two collections like communities and posts. when i inserted a new document in post collection, we need to increment +1 a summary.postCount in communities collection.when i updated the status to deleted in post collection, we need to decrement -1 a summary.postCount in communities collection. I write the function like this.

```
if(changeEvent.operationType == 'insert') {
context.functions.execute('addEventBySystem', 
  {
    community: changeEvent.fullDocument.community,
    channel: changeEvent.fullDocument.channel,
    origin: changeEvent.fullDocument.lastUpdatedBy,
    target: "",
    type: 'created',
    status: 'completed'
  });
if(changeEvent.fullDocument.type == 'article' || changeEvent.fullDocument.type == 'poll' ) {
  context.functions.execute("notifyTopic", "article-created", changeEvent.fullDocument);
  var communities = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("utilo").collection("communities");
  communities.updateOne(
    {_id:changeEvent.fullDocument.community},
    {$inc: {"summary.postCount":1}, $currentDate: {"summary.lastActivity":true} }
  )
} else if(changeEvent.operationType == 'update') {
if(changeEvent.fullDocument.status == "deleted" && changeEvent.fullDocument.type == 'article' || 
changeEvent.fullDocument.type == 'poll') {
  var communities = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("utilo").collection("communities");
  communities.updateOne(
    {_id:changeEvent.fullDocument.community},
    {$inc: {"summary.postCount":-1}, $currentDate: {"summary.lastActivity":true} }
  )
}
```

Now, at the time of decrement, summary.postCount datatype changed from int32 to double. I tried to NumberInt also but no use. How to keep datatype int only after increment/decrement?

Note: In Communities summary filed like this summary:{postCount:1,lastActivity:date}

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely some kind of bug going on here. I was able to kind of get around it by doing `{$inc: {"x": Number(1)}}`. That will still change it to int64, but that's at least closer than a double.